# Can't unzip compressed files - Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: nautilus, 15.04, compression, unzip

So, here's what I'm faced with atm: I am unable to unzip any type of compressed files - 7z, tar, bz, zip, rar, etc. I've tried in front-ends (nautilus and PCMan) and terminal (unzip, tar, etc) and nothing. When I right-click and select Extract here, nothing happens - no dialogue box, no new files, nothing. When I use terminal, it shows some output, but still nothing happens. Not sure what's going on, but I would appreciate help if at all possible. Thanks!

Comment: 7zip does not come with the OS, it needs to be installed. Run `whereis 7z` to see if you have it installed.

Comment: Yeah, I have 7z installed. I figured it out last night, though - file-roller was messed up, so I had to reinstall it. Everything is working now, though. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that file-roller somehow became corrupted. I just had to reinstall it and everything is working.